# Reference generic handler from second project in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have solution with two projects. First is Web, second is something else (SecondProject).
In first project(web) I have aspx page and jquery script with AJAX functions that need reference handler that is in second project. How to do that? Code example:

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("HandlerInSecondProject/GetDataBySample.ashx?q=' + request.term + '") %>',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var obj = data;
                        response($.map(obj, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Term,
                                id: item.ID
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second project should also be a web project, otherwise the handler will not be properly hosted by ASP.NET.  Once the second project is a web project, the URL

```
url: '<%= ResolveUrl("HandlerInSecondProject/GetDataBySample.ashx?q=' + request.term + '") %>',
```

should just refer to the location of the handler on the second web project.

Then, you just need to tell your handler to return json, the `ProcessRequest` method:

```
context.Response.Write(
    jsonSerializer.Serialize(
        new
        {
            Term = "My Term",
            ID = 22
        }
    )
);
```

When you call this from your jQuery, you should get the result back as json and be able to do with it whatever you like.